# Multiple criteria match/search vba

Tags: vba, match

Good day,

I have bashing my head trying to figure out how to program a multiple criteria search on multiple worksheets.

I have 3 ws that has data on row a : date, row b : string, row c: amount. My aim is to find duplicates across all three sheets that have an exact match on column b and c. The resulting matches should be copied onto a newly created sheet.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet, WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet, WS3 As Worksheet
Dim st_cell As Range, frow1 As Range, frow2 As Range, frow3 As Range, mydata As Range, cell As Range, Descr1 As Range, Descr2 As Range, Descr3 As Range
Dim p As Long

Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
Set WS3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)

    Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = "Report"
    Sheets("Report").Range("A1") = "Description"
    Sheets("Report").Range("B1") = "Amount"
    erow = Sheets("Report").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1



    Set st_cell = WS1.Cells(2, 2)
        lastrow = WS1.Cells(WS1.Rows.Count, st_cell.Column).End(xlUp).row


    Set frow1 = WS2.Cells(2, 2)
        lastrow1 = WS2.Cells(WS2.Rows.Count, frow1.Column).End(xlUp).row


    Set frow2 = WS3.Cells(2, 2)
        lastrow2 = WS3.Cells(WS3.Rows.Count, frow2.Column).End(xlUp).row


    With WS1
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        Set Descr1 = WS1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 3))


    For Each Descr1 In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If (Descr1 <> Empty) Then
    For p = 2 To lastrow1 And lastrow2
        Set Descr2 = WS2.Range(Cells(p, 2), Cells(p, 3))
        Set Descr3 = WS3.Range(Cells(p, 2), Cells(p, 3))

                    Set mydata = WS1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 3)).Find(what:=Descr1, after:=.Cells(i, 2), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not mydata Is Nothing Then
                    Sheets("Report").Cells(erow, 1) = WS1.Cells(i, "b")
                    Sheets("Report").Cells(erow, 2) = WS1.Cells(i, "c")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
    Next p
    End If
    Next Descr1


Next i
End With

End Sub
```

When running it I get an error: Worksheet is out of range. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 3 sheets, the line `Set WS3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)` is wrong, as you reference fourth sheet. If you want to have fourth worksheet, you should use `Worksheets.Add` method. To get clear view on how to use that function accordingly to your needs, refer to this [Microsoft site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-add-method-excel).

Comment: HI Michal, the 4th sheet is the main page, I haven't included it in the code copied above but it's there in my file. Also this a part of a much larger code, I just included the relevant part or so I assume.